# dropdown list - confirm - issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have following code in my .aspx

```
<td>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">\
    function ShowConfirm() {
      if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  </script>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1s"  runat="server"  
     onselectedindexchanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
  </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

I have following code in my aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlEnrollmentStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ddl1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ShowConfirm();");
}
```

I have two items in my dropdownlist (Yes and No)

When I select 2nd item from the list, my page refreshes and I get w/e I set up in Page_Load event.

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to create a confirmbox where it asks user to verify if the value they selected is what they intended to select. If they press Yes, change the value to w/e they selected. if they press no, revert back to original value.

Comment: Your code hurts my head. When you change it on the client side, the code behind is somehow supposed to call the javascript ShowConfirm?

Comment: Sorry Yuriy :) Also, none of the codes listed below works. :( I get same page refreshes to page_load state.

Comment: @user1569220 if you think that, it's because you didn't read or try my answer =)  What I said is correct, and mellamokb has confirmed it.

Comment: You need to study how html and javascript work together. It will give you the obvious answer why what you're doing doesn't work. From there you can start to understand the stateless nature of http and how .Net works. Right now you're just shooting darts in the dark. Maybe you'll get it after a few hours, but you won't be any better at shooting darts in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you have entirely client-side validation, it is simplest to do it only in the client code if at all possible:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1s"  runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="True" onchange="return ShowConfirm();">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The mixing of server and client events gets very messy because all server processing happens first, and then the page is sent to the user's browser, then all client events run (and all client context is lost between each round-trip to the server).  Your current code is saying:

1. User changes DropDown value.
2. Round-trip to server.
3. Server sends JavaScript code with `onchange`.
4. Nothing happens.  `onchange` wasn't present when the user actually changed the value (1), and it doesn't fire now because the page is loaded fresh without the knowledge of the change.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue (page refreshes to page_load status. What should I have in aspx.cs file for ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: @user1569220: If the only reason you were using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event was for the validation above, then remove it completely and set `AutoPostBack` to `false`.  There's no need for a server round-trip here.

Comment: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" error in VS comes up. I removed SelectedIndexChanged from aspx/aspx.cs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you need this:

```
ddl1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return ShowConfirm();");
```

Take a look at "return" I wrote.

You can simplify your javascript with this too:

```
function ShowConfirm() {
  return confirm("Are you sure?") == true;
}
```

Comment: some people are really snappy.  There's nothing wrong about your code, other than it not being the right answer.  However, it's no more wrong than any of the others below you who people did not vote on =/  Here's a free upvote to get you to neutral ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I really apreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
ddl1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return ShowConfirm();");
```

**use it on the page load event.**

or bind this with your html (.aspx) page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1s"  runat="server" onchange="return ShowConfirm();"
 onselectedindexchanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
```

Answer (score 1):

`AutoPostBack="True"` is the faulty line of code.  This causes a post back on the control; however, it doesn't track the new value but the old value when it posts back.

You simply need to get your events correctly fired.  Start by setting this attribute to False; and then determine what on your page is responsible for doing the PostBack.